# Upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04. Extremely slow boot now. Any suggestions?

Tags: 14.04, boot, upgrade, 16.04

I don't know why I updated lol. My 14.04 booted in about 3-10 seconds. Now it takes about 3-5 minutes to boot after I upgraded to 16.04.

Any suggestions to speed up the boot time?

I ran `systemd-analyze blame` and this is what i get

```
5.636s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      1.306s apache2.service
      1.055s mysql.service
       791ms apparmor.service
       732ms plymouth-read-write.service
       651ms winbind.service
       651ms nmbd.service
       639ms dev-sda5.device
       592ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       539ms samba-ad-dc.service
       380ms smbd.service
       283ms ModemManager.service
       276ms upower.service
       266ms accounts-daemon.service
       250ms thermald.service
       219ms systemd-logind.service
       218ms NetworkManager.service
       188ms gpu-manager.service
       181ms irqbalance.service
       179ms ondemand.service
       166ms speech-dispatcher.service
       159ms grub-common.service
       148ms apport.service
       130ms lm-sensors.service
       124ms console-setup.service
       122ms binfmt-support.service
       115ms alsa-restore.service
       100ms lightdm.service
        95ms console-kit-log-system-start.service
        90ms systemd-rfkill.service
        88ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        87ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
        87ms pppd-dns.service
        86ms systemd-localed.service
        81ms keyboard-setup.service
        72ms systemd-user-sessions.service
        72ms rsyslog.service
        55ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        54ms udisks2.service
        50ms networking.service
        48ms wpa_supplicant.service
        48ms systemd-journald.service
        44ms console-kit-daemon.service
        39ms polkitd.service
        38ms avahi-daemon.service
        37ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
        37ms colord.service
        37ms plymouth-start.service
        37ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-F607\x2dBE56.service
        33ms systemd-modules-load.service
        32ms user@1000.service
        31ms bluetooth.service
        28ms resolvconf.service
        25ms dns-clean.service
        24ms systemd-hostnamed.service
        23ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
        21ms systemd-udevd.service
        19ms dev-mqueue.mount
        17ms systemd-journal-flush.service
        14ms boot-efi.mount
        13ms systemd-timesyncd.service
        12ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
        12ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
        10ms rtkit-daemon.service
         9ms dev-sda6.swap
         9ms kmod-static-nodes.service
         8ms dev-hugepages.mount
         7ms systemd-remount-fs.service
         7ms ufw.service
         7ms systemd-sysctl.service
         7ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         5ms ureadahead-stop.service
         5ms rc-local.service
         4ms systemd-random-seed.service
         3ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
         3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         3ms setvtrgb.service
         1ms snapd.socket
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I fixed it. My `/etc/fstab` file had the wrong uuid for the swap partition so it was looking for something that did not exist.

I used Disks to see in what partition it was in and then

```
sudo blkid /dev/sda6
```

to get the correct uuid and changed it on my fstab

Comment: This was a great insight for my problem. I had a similar issue with fstab, it was using device names instead of UUIDs (my RAID'd device names changed when upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04).

Comment: @TLin glad I could help. Thats why is always good to post an answer, even to your own question :)